# Clearing stack on navigating

Tags: react-navigation-v5

On react-navigation v4, I was able to clear the stack navigation where navigating to a screen in a stacknavigator with this code :

```
this.props.navigation.dispatch(StackActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    actions: [
        NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'ConfirmRegistration' })
    ]
}))
```

I'm migrating project to react-navigation v5 and after trying several codes, I cannot manage to reproduce the same behaviour.
I've also tried to clear the nav inside the desired screen, with no success (infinite loop) using this code :

```
this.props.navigation.reset({
    index: 0,
    routes: [
        {
            name: 'SignedOut',
            state: {
                routes: [{
                    name: 'SignUp',
                    state: {
                        routes: [{
                            name: 'ConfirmRegistration'
                        }]
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Some help would be really appreciated, especially since the switch navigator has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've just found it.
Seems that calling `navigate('SignUp', {screen: 'ConfirmRegistration'})` does the work.

Comment: After some tests, it doesn't work, it was a side effect of some code